# Cart data not shown in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have made a simple cart in which i want to show selected items in my cart. I can select item successfully when i `print_r` my array it shows the data.Even the count of `session['cart']` increases as well. But unluckily it isn't showing data in my sidebar table. Here is my code. Any suggestions please.I am stuck with this.
[image: First entry update quantity]
[image: 2nd pic]

**Code**

```
     <?php

        if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action']=="add"){
           $id=intval($_GET['id']);
$size = $_GET['size'];
$color = $_GET['color'];
    //$index=$id.$color.$size;
$sql_p="SELECT * FROM products WHERE productid={$id}";

$query_p=mysqli_query($con, $sql_p);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_p)!=0){
    $row_p=mysqli_fetch_array($query_p);
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id])  && isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]['color']) && $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['color'] == $color && isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]['size']) && $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['size'] == $size)
        {
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
           // $_SESSION['cart'][$index] = array('quantity' => $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity'], 'price' => $row_p['product_price'], 'id' => $id, 'size' => $size, 'color' => $color, 'name' => $row_p['product_name']);

            print_r($_SESSION['cart'][$id]);
            echo "\n";
            //print_r($_SESSION['cart'][$index]);

            echo "<script>alert('".$row_p['product_name']." has been added to your cart.');</script>";
}
else{

   // $_SESSION['cart'][$index]=array("quantity" => 1, "price" => $row_p['product_price'],"color"=> $color,"size"=> $size,"name"=>$row_p['product_name']);
     $_SESSION['cart'][$row_p['productid']]=array("quantity" => 1, "price" => $row_p['product_price'],"color"=> $color,"size"=> $size,"name"=>$row_p['product_name']);
       print_r($_SESSION['cart'][$row_p['productid']]);
    }
}
}
?>
```

**cart table**

```
     <div id="sidebar">
            <h1>Cart:   <?php echo  count($_SESSION['cart']); ?></h1>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>color</th>
                    <th>size</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){

                        $sql="Select * from products where productid IN (";
                        foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value){
                            $sql .=$id. ",";
                        }

                        $sql=substr($sql,0,-1) . ") ORDER BY productid ASC";
                        $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                        if(!empty($query)){
                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

                                ?>




                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['productid'] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['product_name']?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['productid']]['quantity']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo  $_SESSION['cart'][$row['productid']]['color']?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][$row['productid']]['size'] ?></td>
                            <td><a href="index.php?page=remove_from_cart&action=remove&id=<?php echo $row['productid']; ?>">x</a> </td>
                        </tr>

                    <?php

                    }
                    }
                    ?>

          <tr><td colspan="3"><a href="index.php?page=cart">Go To Cart</a></td></tr> <tr><td><?php echo "Your Cart is Empty"; ?></td></tr>

        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: @Steve can you please elaborate this with some code which i can understand easily!

Comment: once you get it working you need to make your `$GET['...` variables safe by sanitizing them and escaping them - asap really. The comments at the bottom of this post might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838137/php-registration-form-complication/33839368#33839368

Comment: @Steve the line you edited didn't worked for me. I have edited my code again. I am editing here as well. This code worked but problem is when i select `item1` with color `yellow` and size `XL`. It shows data in cart table. Now if i again select the same item with same size and same color it just updates the quantity in the table!! Till here it works fine!! But problem when i select the same item with different color and size, it replaces the old table row with same id num. I want to show another row for this. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: I am not sure if your $id you are searching by it the same as $index -  $index seems to contain size and colour identifiers - I couldn't make out where the data was being put back into the database so it would be found by the search as `$row[...`

Comment: @Steve updated my code. Please have a look. I have removed $index. It works as i have mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: I think you were on the right track with the `$index` which included colour/size information so it would create a second entry/id rather than replacing what was there because it has the same id.  Is it possible for each item to have its own id which includes size and colour like `$index` did? If so, I think that would work the way you have it structured currently. Getting warnings about moving this to chat but I don't really have any more ideas, sorry.

Comment: Seriously consider using a framework, symfony, lavaral, Zend - your life will get better!